# Почему не работает соовсем простецкий example (Python | vk_api)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Всем привет! Нужно сделать так, чтобы бот отправил мне хоть какой-то месседж, а скрип на питоне даже не хочет работать (пытаюсь авторизоваться как группа)....
Вопрос: Почему?
Вот код:
    import time

```
import vk_api

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = 'СКРЫТ В ЦЕЛЯХ БЕЗОПАСНОСТИ')

vk_api = vk.get_api()

LongPoll = vk_api.VkBotLongPoll(vk, 161827083, wait=20)

vk.auth()
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cheater/Документы/2pb.py", line 9, in <module>
    LongPoll = vk_api.VkBotLongPoll(vk, 161827083, wait=20)
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Токен полностью рабочий, выставлены все разрешения, LongPoll включен.

Comment: Потому что вы затёрли модуль `vk_api` своей новой переменной `vk_api = ...` и в итоге всё сломали. Кроме того, `VkBotLongPoll` находится в подмодуле `bot_longpoll`, который у вас нигде в коде почему-то не упомянут — читайте документацию внимательнее

Comment: Спасибо, я поменял всё как нужно (вроде), но всё ровно не работает :(
Вот код:
https://pastebin.com/bc7X7nbL Ошибка: https://pastebin.com/sRfSFFem

Comment: В модуле `vk_api` не существует никакого `VkBotLongPoll`, а вы всё ещё продолжаете к нему обращаться — читайте документацию ещё внимательнее. И примеры тоже читайте https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/bot_longpoll.py

Comment: @andreymal, я скопировал код из примера (https://pastebin.com/D7qJKVn1), но всё ровно ошибка кидается https://pastebin.com/RfNsxH1N

Comment: Потому что пример для третьего питона, а вы его запускаете во втором. Зачем вам второй питон?

Comment: @andreymal, я забыл поставить pip для 3 версии) Поставил, скачал модуль и всё работает. Спасибо!11  Код такой: https://pastebin.com/JVGDR2AE